# Can I use one Bootstrap column width (not equaling 12) in separate rows?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been trying to create two separate Bootstrap rows, each with a width of 8.

Unfortunately, both rows overlap each other.  I've tried various approaches to solving the problem but nothing is working.

I'm curious if this is a problem with the way I'm using column widths.

Sorry for such a simple question - I'm fairly new to all of this.

## HTML

```
<div class="container">

  <!-- HEADLINE -->

<div class="row">
    <div class="short-description col-xs-8">

      <div class="listing-headline">
          {{ adContent?.headline }}
      </div>

      <div class="location-info">
          {{ location?.city }}, {{ location?.state }}, {{ location?.country }}
      </div>

  <hr>
    </div>

</div>




<!-- DETAILS OVERVIEW -->
<div class="row">
      <div class="details-overview col-xs-8" *ngFor="let info of unitContent">

          <div class="rental-type">
              {{ info?.unitContent.propertyType }}
          </div>

          <div class="guest-allowance">

          </div>

          <div class="space-type">

          </div>

          <div class="bed-number">

          </div>



          <hr>
        </div>
</div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.short-description {
  height: 80px;
  padding: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


.listing-headline {
  font-style: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 120%;
}

.location-info {
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}


.details-overview {
}
```

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are asking for. It sounds like you may be looking for the offset class? Add .col-md-offset-4 to the div css

Comment: Try using the <div class="clearfix"></div> to start your second div on the next line.

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Your Bootstrap looks fine to me. I think it might be a CSS issue because if you remove the CSS there's no overlap.

Adding a margin-top in .details-overview may help.

Answer (score 1):

Your class **.listing-headline** has a to big font size / line height for your **.short-description** class with height of 80px;

You have to **decrease the font size** or **increase the height** of **.short-description** for avoiding overlapping in your case.

When you delete the height of **.short-description** it looks nice:

```
    .short-description {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothings wrong with your code. I think overlapping of  both rows  with each other is because of some codes missing with bootstrap stylesheets (either of bootstrap.css or bootstrap.min.css) you are using. It's better to get a new copy of it.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="listing-headline">
                HEADLINE 1
            </div>
            <!--/col-xs-8-->
            <div class="location-info">
                CITY, STATE, COUNTRY
            </div>
            <!--/col-xs-8-->
            <hr>
        </div>
        <!--/col-xs-8-->
    </div>
    <!--/row-->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="rental-type">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </div>
            <!--/rental-type-->
            <div class="guest-allowance">
            </div>
            <!--/guest-allowance-->

            <div class="space-type">
            </div>
            <!--/space-type-->

            <div class="bed-number">
            </div>
            <!--/bed-number-->
            <hr>
        </div>
        <!--/col-xs-8-->
    </div>
    <!--/row-->
</div>
<!--/container-->

<style type="text/css">
    .short-description {
        height: 80px;
        padding: auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .listing-headline {
        font-style: bold;
        font-size: 3em;
        line-height: 120%;
    }
    .location-info {
        margin-top: 5px;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 1.4em;
    }
</style>
```